# Vue-Router passing data to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am having a problem with passing data from one component to another using Vue-Router.

I have this template in the main component:

```
<li><router-link to="/">Daily</router-link></li>
<li><router-link to="/weekly/">Weekly</router-link></li>
<router-view></router-view>
```

And in my `DailyComponent` component, I have this data function:

```
data() {
  return {
    userCount: 0,
  }
}
```

The second link sends to the component named `WeeklyComponent`.

How can I pass the `userCount: 0` data from `DailyComponent` to `WeeklyComponent` and then display it there?

Thanks!

Comment: You can find information at https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html. Or you can manage the state passing using https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html.

Comment: thank you for your fast response, I will check the links you gave

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is more about how to architect the components in such a way to share data between them. There are many ways to do this, each with their own pros and cons depending on the situation. I suggest you search stackoverflow/google for ways to do this because it has been discussed in depth.

**Raise the owner of the `userCount` data to the parent**

Make the parent component the owner of the `userCount` data, and pass this down to the child components via props. If the child components want to modify that data, they must `$emit` an event with the new value which the parent responds to so it can update the value.

```js
const Daily = {
  props: ['userCount'],
  template: '<p>Daily: {{ userCount }} <button @click="increment">+ 1</button></p>',
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$emit('user-count', this.userCount + 1);
    }
  }
};

const Weekly = {
  props: ['userCount'],
  template: '<p>Weekly: {{ userCount }} <button @click="increment">+ 5</button></p>',
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$emit('user-count', this.userCount + 5);
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { path: '/daily', component: Daily },
      { path: '/weekly', component: Weekly }
    ]
  }),
  data: {
    userCount: 0,
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue-router/dev/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/daily">Daily</router-link>
  <router-link to="/weekly">Weekly</router-link>
  
  <router-view :user-count="userCount" @user-count="userCount = $event"></router-view>
</div>
```

**Vuex or some other external state management**

There's already lots of Vuex examples so I won't replicate that here, but you can come up with any kind of state management system you want.

Vuex may be overkill for your example. You can just pass around a shared reactive object instead.

```js
const Daily = {
  props: ['shared'],
  template: '<p>Daily: {{ shared.userCount }} <button @click="increment">+ 1</button></p>',
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.shared.userCount += 1;
    }
  }
};

const Weekly = {
  props: ['shared'],
  template: '<p>Weekly: {{ shared.userCount }} <button @click="increment">+ 5</button></p>',
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.shared.userCount += 5;
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: [
      { path: '/daily', component: Daily },
      { path: '/weekly', component: Weekly }
    ]
  }),
  data: {
    shared: {
      userCount: 0,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue-router/dev/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/daily">Daily</router-link>
  <router-link to="/weekly">Weekly</router-link>
  
  <router-view :shared="shared"></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: what a very useful answer you got there @Decade Moon! Thank you so much for giving me your time to answer my question!

Comment: @Decade Moon For the props-way of doing it: Why do you use `'user-count'` in the `this.$emit` function and not `userCount`? What is `'user-count'` referring to?

Comment: @BennettDams `userCount` would be the preferred event name, but attributes in HTML are case-insensitive, so Vue would read `@userCount` as `@usercount` and it wouldn't work. I used `user-count` (kebab case) as a lowercase compromise (you could use `usercount` too but that doesn't separate the words). If you're using single file components with a webpack build then this does not apply and you can use `$emit('userCount', ...)` and `@userCount` instead.

Comment: So you use `user-count` in the router view to "bind" the value? Could you explain what `@user-count="userCount = $event"` in the router view is for, then? I know `@click`etc., but what is `@user-count` used for?

Comment: `@user-count` is an event listener for the `user-count` event, and the `user-count` event is emitted by the component when it wants to change the value of `userCount` in the parent. `userCount = $event` is the listener function which sets `this.userCount` to the event parameter (the parameter is `x` in `$emit('user-count', x)`).

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, any props or events you bind to `<router-view>` will be bound to the route component (either `Daily` or `Weekly`, whichever is active).

Comment: This only works when using the Vue CDN, right? When using the CLI and the standard config, I will get an error:   error  Unexpected mutation of "shared" prop  vue/no-mutating-props

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) or a [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). You can also have a common parent component to both components.

If you use an event bus, you can emit events with the values and listen to them anywhere in the app. If you have a common parent component, you can pass `userCount` to both child components as a prop and then emit events from the child components to the parent.  Every time a child wants to change the value, it emits the event and then the parent changes the value on its behalf.